# Overlaying images with transparency in UIAxes

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-app-designer

I am trying to display 2 overlaid images in an app within a UIAxes.
I know about `imshowpair(bg,fg,'blend')`, and although it does work, it doesn't allow me to control the transparency level.

I tried following [Steve's tip](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2009/02/18/image-overlay-using-transparency), where he recommends using:

```
f1 = imshow(fig1); 
f2 = imshow(fig2);
set(f2,'AlphaData',alpha)
```

but it doesn't work properly within a UIAxes. When I set the `'AlphaData'` property, both images become transparent.

How can I do this? The idea would be to have a slider where the user can set the transparency of the top image interactively.

### Reference code and images

```
f1 = imshow(ref,'Parent',app.UIAxes);
hold on
f2 = imshow(gbT2,'Parent',app.UIAxes);
hold off
set(f2,'AlphaData', alpha);
```

How it looks in a figure vs how it looks in UIAxes:

[image: figure vs UIAxes]

Comment: Blending images is often just a weighted sum of the two images. If they are the same size and are `uint8` type then you could just do `figBlend = uint8(alpha*fig1 + (1-alpha)*fig2)` where `alpha` is a number between 0 and 1 that controls the amount of blending.

Comment: I am not sure they are uint8, I imported from tiff with `imread(img)`.
What if they are not the same size (they are not)? I could crop them, but would prefer another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Running in R2018a, I'm not able to reproduce this. This is the code I used though:

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
f1 = imshow(I,'Parent',app.UIAxes);
hold(app.UIAxes, 'on')

I2 = imread('pout.tif');
f2 = imshow(I2,'Parent',app.UIAxes);
hold(app.UIAxes, 'off')

set(f2,'AlphaData', 0.5);
```